# win32api - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, winapi, dll, jupyter, dllimport

I am trying to install Jupyter simply by following the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html). I used `pip`.
The installation went fine, but while trying to open Jupyter using `jupyter lab` in the command prompt I got the following error right after it was trying to import `win32api`.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

How do I fix this?

my `pip` version is 21.0.1
[image: error msg cmd]

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I had two Python versions installed. So I deleted all and installed the newest one. Seemed to me like the `PATH` for `win32api` got mixed up with the previous versions.
Also, spare yourself the manually installation hassle with `pip` and get Anaconda- this will install for you Jupyter automatically.
I spent so much time trying to figure out what's the issue with `pip` while Anaconda can spare you so much trouble.